# Defining one-to-one dependencies between multiple parallel matrix jobs in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In a gitlab pipeline, I can specify a job like:

```yaml
build:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - architecture: [x86_64, arm]
        operating_system: [linux, macos]
```

And that will create 4 separate jobs that can all run in parallel:

- `build [x86_64, linux]`
- `build [x86_64, macos]`
- `build [arm, linux]`
- `build [arm, macos]`

I can also specify another job like:

```yaml
test:
  needs:
    - job: build
      parallel:
        matrix:
          - architecture: [x86_64, arm]
            operating_system: [linux, macos]
```

And that would create one more job named `test` that would wait for all 4 `build` jobs to run before starting.

But what If I wanted 4 separate `test` jobs, one for each combo of `architecture` and `operating_system`, just like the `build` jobs? I would want something like:

```yaml
test:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - architecture: [x86_64, arm]
        operating_system: [linux, macos]
  needs:
    - job: build
      parallel:
        matrix:
          - architecture: [x86_64, arm]
            operating_system: [linux, macos]
```

But, I'm assuming that would create 4 separate `test` jobs that would each depend on all of the 4 separate `build` jobs. What I'd want is for each of the `test` jobs to only depend on a single `build` job with the same variables. In the past, I've tried to use variables in the `needs` array, but this was before `needs:parallel:matrix` was introduced, and it didn't work anyway. Can you use variables in `needs:parallel:matrix` to achieve this? Something like:

```yaml
test:
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - architecture: [x86_64, arm]
        operating_system: [linux, macos]
  needs:
    - job: build
      parallel:
        matrix:
          - architecture: [$architecture]
            operating_system: [$operating_system]
```

Comment: It appears that variables are still not allowed in `needs:`. So the proposed solution won't work.